# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jest-mock-axios

when try to mock the post call with jest getting error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
```

any one help me to understand please? here is the spect code:

```
 const mockFn = jest.fn();
  axios.post = mockFn;
  userEvent.click(button);

  const apiCall = mockFn.mock.calls[0];
  const body = apiCall[1];
  expect(body).toEqual({ userName: "arif", password: "one", email: "xyz@abc.com" });
```

template:

```
const submit = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post("/api/1.0/users", formData);
    setFormData(initialFormProps);
  };
```

html:

```
<form action="" autoComplete="off">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="userName" onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={formData.userName} name="userName" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="userEmail" onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={formData.userEmail} name="userEmail" />
        <input type="password" defaultValue={formData.userPassword} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="userPassword" name="userPassword" />
        <input type="password" defaultValue={formData.userPasswordRep} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="userPassword Repeat" name="userPasswordRep" />
        <button disabled={isSubmit} onClick={submit}>
          Sign Up{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
```

testing part:

```
it("sends username, email and password to backend after clicking submit", async () => {
      render(<SignUpPage />);
      const password = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userPassword");
      const userName = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userName");
      const email = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userEmail");
      userEvent.type(password, "one");
      userEvent.type(userName, "arif");
      userEvent.type(email, "xyz@abc.com");
      const button = screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "Sign Up" }) as HTMLElement;

      const mockFn = jest.fn();
      axios.post = mockFn;
      userEvent.click(button);

      const apiCall = mockFn.mock.calls[0];
      const body = apiCall[1];
      expect(body).toEqual({ userName: "arif", password: "one", email: "xyz@abc.com" });
    });
```

Comment: Presumably `apiCall` is `undefined`, which means `mockFn.mock.calls` was an empty array. Without a [mre] it's hard to see why you expected otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - added template and code part. if needs more info let me know

Answer (score -1):

it is working fine after i remove `jest.mock('axios');`
here is the passing test:

```
it("sends username, email and password to backend after clicking submit", async () => {
  render(<SignUpPage />);
  const password = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userPassword");
  const userName = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userName");
  const email = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userEmail");
  const rePass = screen.getByPlaceholderText("userPassword Repeat");
  userEvent.type(password, "one");
  userEvent.type(userName, "arif");
  userEvent.type(email, "xyz@abc.com");
  userEvent.type(rePass, "one");
  const button = screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "Sign Up" }) as HTMLElement;
  const payload = { userPassword: "one", userName: "arif", userEmail: "xyz@abc.com", userPasswordRep: "one" };
  const mockFn = jest.fn();
  axios.post = mockFn;
  userEvent.click(button);

  const apiCall = mockFn.mock.calls[0];
  const body = apiCall[1];
  expect(body).toEqual(payload);
});
```